# How to print the second part of pair? EX: pair<int, pair<int,int> >

Tags: c++, stl, keyvaluepair

I've been stuck on this for a while, I'm trying to pair some data together. Here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   pair<int, int> data(31,8);
   pair<int, pair<int,int> > newData(4,data);

   cout << newData.second<< endl;

   return 0;. 
}
```

However I get lots of errors, I just need someone to point me in the right direction. If you type:

```
cout << newData.first << endl;
```

That works fine, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`newData.second` is a pair, so you access its members just like you do for `data`.  `newdata.second.first` and `newdata.second.second`.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider `std::tuple` since, in the end, you're joining data with more a pair of parts.

But as long as you stick to your current form, you should use `newData.first` for the first part, `newData.second.first` for the first part of the second part, and `newData.second.second` for the second part of the second part.

Again, consider `std::tuple`.